# Sendgrid - BCC API to be removed from Mail Settings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3, sendgrid-rails

I am using Sendgrid in my Rails application for sending emails. I got an email from Sengrid saying that:

```
We’re emailing you with an update concerning the retirement of the BCC feature of our Email API. Our records show that you are still using the BCC feature.

If our previous correspondence regarding the removal of BCC did not make it your way, we apologize. We strive to provide thorough communication and ample warning of feature deprecations and removals. We recognize the change caught some customers by surprise.

To help you make any necessary changes to your sends, the BCC feature under settings will be available until June 22nd, 2020. This feature is now unavailable from the UI and only accessible via API call. We understand that removing a service or feature requires time on the part of our customers, and we hope that extending the availability of BCC is helpful.

Again, the BCC feature will be fully removed June 22nd, 2020.
```

How can I use the BCC feature from now on in Sendgrid?

Answer (score 0):

The [Personalization](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/sendgrid-ruby/4.0.1/SendGrid/Personalization) Object of the Ruby APi do the job. It will allow you to set the BCC programaticaly.

I made the required update in my Java application like this.

```
final Personalization mailPersonalize = new Personalization();
mailPersonalize.addBcc(yourBcc);

final Request request = new Request();

final Mail mail = new Mail();
mail.addPersonalization(mailPersonalize);
request.setBody(mail.buildPretty());
final Response response = sendGrid.api(request);
```

If you are using Personalization to set the BCC, remove it as it will be deprecated. I hope this will help.